# SQL need for below usecase

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE dipti_test.opinions (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,  
  place VARCHAR(255),
  opinion VARCHAR(255)
);

insert into dipti_test.opinions values (1, 'mount nawo oz', 'recommended');
insert into dipti_test.opinions values (2, 'mount nawo oz', 'not recommended');
insert into dipti_test.opinions values (3, 'codility', 'recommended');
insert into dipti_test.opinions values (4, 'codility', 'recommended');
insert into dipti_test.opinions values (5, 'codility', 'recommended'); 
insert into dipti_test.opinions values (6, 'qr week', 'recommended');
insert into dipti_test.opinions values (7, 'qr week', 'not recommended');
insert into dipti_test.opinions values (8, 'cafe worst', 'not recommended'); 
insert into dipti_test.opinions values (9, 'mount nawo oz', 'recommended');
```

Query Should return -

```
     place
   ---------------
    codility
    mount nawo oz
```

Comment: Describe why you want that result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to only return places with more recommended than not recommended:

```
select place
from dipti_test.opinions 
group by place
having sum(case when opinion = 'recommended' then 1
                when opinion = 'not recommended' then -1
           end) > 0
```

Comment: @diptiranjanpradhan . . . This answer is actually correct and should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the below query:

```
    select distinct place
    from opinions 
    group by place
    having sum(case when opinion = 'recommended' then 1
       end) > 0
```

Comment: qr week is also recommended.

Comment: place
   ---------------
    codility
    mount nawo oz
 qr week

Comment: @diptiranjanpradhan , Could you please explain?

Comment: where recommended is more than not recommended

Comment: @diptiranjanpradhan , i think now it will satisfy your requirement.

Comment: @diptiranjanpradhan . . . You have accepted an answer that produces a result different from what the question asks.  That seems really strange, especially when there is another answer that is actually correct.